# How to transfer Google Cloud project ownership?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, administration, google-cloud-platform

I would like to transfer ownership of Google Cloud project completely. By completely I mean rather than sharing ownership between multiple users, removing my account from project. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

1. Share your project with a destination account using Permissions/Add Member/Is Owner
2. Accept invitation from destination account.
3. Remove yourself from this project. (Permissions/Select your account/Remove)

Comment: Do you know if this cover Google Storage API keys, buckets and content?

Comment: Yes, it will transfer ownership of everything as is.

Comment: Is it possible to transfer ownership just of a single GCS bucket?

Comment: @IvanBalashov sure, just edit bucket's permissions. Add new owner and later remove the old one.

Comment: How do you "accept" the invitation? I added my other Gmail account as the owner, but never received an email to that account or any other notification to accept the invitation.

Comment: @maxko87 possibly that they don't require confirmation anymore. Just check the list of projects available for you in the console.

Comment: @DmytroSadovnychyi ah I got it. You have to add the new email address as a role under IAM, not as a permission for the service accounts.

Comment: After the transfer of ownership is completed, I deleted the original email that I used to create, then the project is deleted, why so ?

Comment: This completely destroyed my project/permissions.

Answer (score 75):

In case there are still people looking for the answer, the process may have changed a little bit. As of December 2018 -

1. Navigate to your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Click the "hamburger" menu button.
   [Click Menu Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqLEN.png)
3. Select "IAM" under "Access"
   [Click IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rnJj.png)
4. At the top, click "ADD"
   [Click ADD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgTIU.png)
5. Name the new Owner and select "Owner" under "Project"
   [Select Owner under Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtR9h.png)
6. Instruct your new Owner to Accept the Invitation
7. On new Owner's account, go to Billing in the "hamburger" menu and either link the project to an existing billing account or set up a new Billing account to link the project to.
8. On the new Owner's account, go back to the IAM section and delete your account from the list by clicking the pencil on the right and then the trash can icon.
   [Pencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbBt1.png)
   [Trash can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbHGQ.png)

Comment: This works. My question is who pays for the accrued costs for the month before the new billing account was added, the former or the new billing account?

Answer (score 20):

After the transfer of ownership is completed, you will need to change the billing account too, in order to link it to the billing account of the new user

Comment: you're saying my account will continue to be billed if the receiver doesn't swap in their info?

Answer (score 16):

1. Go to `IAM and Admin`
2. Then Select `IAM`
3. Click `Add`
4. Provide another user's email and select roles as `Project owner`
5. Once another user accept your invitation you can remove yourself.
6. In Billing Section, modify Billing account/

Comment: When doing it this way, are your relying on the new owner to change the billing details or do you still have access to those after you've removed yourself from the project. The reason I ask is because I'd like to use this approach when developing for clients, but I don't want to hand over my billing details or have to chase them up later on...

Comment: @TheGingerFox Here's what I did. After creating the project I've (1) unlinked my personal billing account, (2) invited the client as a project owner, (3) asked the client to set up a billing account for the project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I dont thing is possible but one thing you can do is add another admin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30158412)