# Migrating a GCP project to another email/account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to change the email address behind the Google cloud platform project or if that is not possible i want to migrate the project to the new account. How can that be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer Google Cloud project ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697766/how-to-transfer-google-cloud-project-ownership)

Comment: answer is already given  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697766/how-to-transfer-google-cloud-project-ownership

Answer (score 3):

Using Cloud IAM you can do this in 2 steps:

1. "Add" a new identity (email address) as an "owner" of the project
2. "Remove" the current identity from being an "owner" of the project.

Go to the console in your browser, navigate to your project you want to update, go to "IAM & admin", and perform the above steps.

Comment: Add one more step. Change the Billing Account for the project.

Comment: The question was only about an email account.  Billing is an independent concern from the "owner" roles bound to a project.

Comment: The question is migrating a project. If you are migrating (changing ownership/control), you probably also want to change the billing account. These are separate but interrelated items for Google Cloud Project management.

Comment: how you changing the billing account for the project? I migrated the owner