# How to transfer Google Cloud account without billing account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud account that I need to transfer, but I pay for it right now so I'm wondering what happens to the billing account. Will it also be transferred and I will pay for it until new owner changes (being on his mercy in such case)?

I know [How to transfer Google Cloud project ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697766/how-to-transfer-google-cloud-project-ownership) thread, but users asking about billing weren't answered so I ask specifically about this. What would be the easiest way? I have four containers working there so don't really want to ask new owner to redeploy them on his own. Also, will external links to those containers be the same after transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Once your google account is transferred, they need to [add or create the new billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/create-billing-account) and once it is added you need to [close the original billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account). Google will send you an email detailing the outstanding balance on the account at the time of closure, and it will be charged to the card on file.
- Charges start accruing on the new account the same day the new account is opened. Charges for that day could be split between the old and new accounts depending on the time of usage. When the charge is due depends on [your billing cycle](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-cycle?visit_id=638321007795285103-4134853929&rd=1).
- As you are transferring your account along with the resources , then there is no need to redeploy a new account.
- As external links can be accessed by everyone , it will not change.
- For more information, you can [contact cloud billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#contact-billing-support).